# How do I put a scrollbar inside of a gtk.ComboBoxEntry?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk

I have a Combobox with over a hundred of entries and it is very awkward to skim through with out a scrollbar.

[alt text http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/6972/screenshotprubapy.png](http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/6972/screenshotprubapy.png)

I want to do exactly what is in the picture. With the scrollbar on the right so It'd be easier to move through the entries. I used gtk.Combo to make that example but the problem is that is deprecated.

I need an example of how would you do what is **exactly** the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pygtk
import gtk
import gobject

def window_delete_event(*args):
    return False

def window_destroy(*args):
    gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = gtk.Window()

    # combo's model
    model = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING)
    for n in xrange(100):
        model.append([str(n)])

    # combo
    combo = gtk.ComboBoxEntry(model)
    win.add(combo)

    # combo's style
    style = gtk.rc_parse_string('''
        style "my-style" { GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 1 }
        widget "*.mycombo" style "my-style"
    ''')
    combo.set_name('mycombo')
    combo.set_style(style)

    win.show_all()
    win.connect('delete-event', window_delete_event)
    win.connect('destroy', window_destroy)
    gtk.main()
```